# How to create sub table of contents in a specific section of band report in jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to design a report using jasper reports which has main table of content for the whole report and a sub table of content at the starting of a specific section. The problem that it is not valid to use nested books. So is there another way to do that?

I have 3 parts in the report. The first and the third parts are table of contents. When the second part contains a bookmarkLevel, both table of contents don't work properly. Whenever I remove the bookmarkLeve, both table of contents work properly.

```
<group name="dummy">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[1]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <part evaluationTime="Report" uuid="1fadcc2f-31c1-49be-bd52-f8b69e38cd83">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
            <partNameExpression><![CDATA["Table of Contents"]]></partNameExpression>
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd" usingCache="true">
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TOCPart.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
        <part uuid="3f63c482-39b2-43f1-a623-15fb046605a5">
            <partNameExpression><![CDATA["Overview"]]></partNameExpression>
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["OrdersReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
        <part evaluationTime="Report" uuid="1fadcc2f-31c1-49be-bd52-f8b69e38cd84">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
            <partNameExpression><![CDATA["Table of Contents2"]]></partNameExpression>
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TOCPart2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

Comment: What do you mean by nested books, Sub table? Your question is not clear. Provide some sample design and what you want to achieve in your design.

Comment: @Viki888 Thank you. I have added more details along with an example.